# Entity Framework с PostgreSQL генерирует неправильные типы столбцов

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Имеется проект на ASP.net core 2.2, EF 2.2 и стоит плагин для работы с PostgreSQL - npsql v 2.1.1. Используется подход Code-first.
Есть класс:

```
    public class MobileUser : IEntityBase
    {
        #region Базовые поля

        [Key]
        [MaxLength(36)]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

        public DateTime Created { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(36)]
        public string ProjectId { get; set; }

        #endregion

        public string FIO { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public string LogoPath { get; set; }
        public string Token { get; set; }
        public DateTime TokenExpiredDate { get; set; }
        public bool IsActivated { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastMessageDate { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
    }
```

На основе которого генерируется запрос в бд:

```sql
     CREATE TABLE "MobileUsers" (
              "Id" character varying(36) NOT NULL,
              "IsDeleted" boolean NOT NULL,
              "Created" timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
              "ProjectId" character varying(36) NOT NULL,
              "FIO" text NULL,
              "Email" text NULL,
              "PasswordHash" text NULL,
              "Phone" text NULL,
              "LogoPath" text NULL,
              "Token" text NULL,
              "TokenExpiredDate" text NULL,
              CONSTRAINT "PK_MobileUsers" PRIMARY KEY ("Id")
          );
```

В итоге, в таблице Postgre в столбцах TokenExpiredDate и LastMessageDate стоит тип text, в то время как у Created - timestamp without timezone. Из-за этого, при попытке получить список объектов код падает в ошибку

> Can't cast database type text to DateTime

Как такое возможно и в чем может быть причина?

Comment: Хм, в показанном sql нет поля LastMessageDate. Эта таблица точно была сгенерирована с помощью CodeFirst? Есть сомнения в этом. Может, это другая таблица, сгенерированная в прошлый раз, когда набор свойств в классе был другим? Удалите полностью БД и попробуйте заново.

Comment: Спасибо за наводку, проблема была в миграциях. Почему-то в первых миграциях был тип text, а потом стал dateTime. Исправил файлы миграций и все заработало

Answer (score 0):

Возможно дело в том что у вас уже установлен
"TokenExpiredDate" text NULL,
                  // Тут text
    В общем когда в базу передается запрос на создания таблицы вы можете указать тип текст или иное.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, не совсем понял, имеете в виду сразу передавать тип text?